# pass selected value of my combo box to another input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass the selected value of my combo box to the the input value which has a id of "val".

I tried passing the value using jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btn').click(function(e) {
                $('#combobox').change(function() {
                    var selected = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
                    alert($('#val').val(selected));
                });

            });
        });
```

But it's not working. Please help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Form</h1>
  <form method="post" id="form" name="form">
   <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" style="margin-top: 10px;">Choice</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5 selectContainer">
     <select id="combobox" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <input id="val" type="hidden" name="val"> 
    <input id="btn" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit">
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>

 <script type=text/javascript>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn').click(function(e) {
    $('#combobox').change(function() {
     var selected = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
     alert($('#val').val(selected));
    });

   });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have nested your event handlers. Change within click. That is always a sign that the code is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please note it is custom to award first answers when similar answers are posted (not the last one added later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.change` is not neccessary. On the Button click you can directly access the selected value of your dropdown. Please check the below code.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn').click(function(e) {
     alert($('#combobox option:selected').val());
   });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Form</h1>
  <form method="post" id="form" name="form">
   <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" style="margin-top: 10px;">Choice</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5 selectContainer">
     <select id="combobox" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <input id="val" type="hidden" name="val"> 
    <input id="btn" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit">
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the click event in `#btn`

```
$('#combobox').change(function() {
    var selected = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
    $('#val').val(selected)
    alert($('#val').val());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

You have nested your event handlers. Change within click. That is always a sign that the code is wrong. You will be adding a new change handler on every click, which is not what you want.

It is not 100% clear what you are trying to do, but you can start like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('#combobox').change(function() {
       var selected = $(this).val();
       $('#val').val(selected);
       alert($('#val').val());
   });
});
```

Note: `val()` on a `select` will return the selected value, so you do not need to use `option:selected` and its `text`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Form</h1>
  <form method="post" id="form" name="form">
   <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" style="margin-top: 10px;">Choice</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5 selectContainer">
     <select id="combobox" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <input id="val" type="hidden" name="val"> 
    <input id="btn" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit">
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>

 <script type=text/javascript>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   
    $('#combobox').change(function() {
     var selected = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
$('#val').val(selected)
alert($('#val').val());
    

   });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```